# Location.distanceBetween doesn't get distance, range, meters, and not recognize latlong variables

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get range from user if him let circle, but I can't get the range or the distance in screen, it always show 0.0, and don't show the toast.

```java
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after
     returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    LatLng latLng;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    Marker marker;

    //textview para mostrar el email, nombre, id del usuario conectado actualmente
    TextView textViewEmail;

    Context context;

    double latitudeF, longitudeF;

    TextView locationText;
    TextView tiempoText;
    TextView rangoText;
    TextView longitudeText;
    TextView latitudeText;

    //Float distance;

    Circle circle;

    String dist;

    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager
                ().findFragmentById(R.id.mapHomeUbication);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        context = this;

        // inicializamos el textview
        textViewEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_EmailUsuario);
        locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        longitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        latitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        tiempoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiempo);
        rangoText = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.rango);

        // cargamos el email desde sharedpreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences
                (Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "No Disponible");

        // mostramos el email actualmente logueado
        textViewEmail.setText("Usuario : " + email);

        onMapReady(mMap);

    }

    // function salir
    private void logout() {
        //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Esta seguro que quiere salir?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Sí",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    //Getting out sharedpreferences
                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences
                            (Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    //Getting editor
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                    //Puting the value false for loggedin
                    editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                    //Putting blank value to email
                    editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

                    //Saving the sharedpreferences
                    editor.commit();

                    //Starting login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

        //Showing the alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Adding our menu to toolbar
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.log_OutMenu) {
            //calling logout method when the logout button is clicked
            logout();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        setUpMap();
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
     In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener());
        }
    }

    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener() {
        return new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng latLngI  = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
                longitudeF = location.getLongitude();
                latitudeF = location.getLatitude();

                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
                String formatted = format.format(date);
                tiempoText.setText(formatted.toString());

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng
                        (latitudeF, longitudeF), 13));

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker

                options.position(new LatLng(latitudeF, longitudeF));

                latLng = new LatLng(latitudeF, longitudeF);

                drawMarkerWithCircle(latLng);

                // Get back the mutable Circle
                //circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

                //getDistance(latLngI, latLng);

                float[] distance = new float[2];

                Location.distanceBetween( marker.getPosition().latitude,
                        marker.getPosition().longitude,
                        circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter
                                ().longitude, distance);

                if (distance[0] > circle.getRadius()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fuera del rango: "
                            + distance[0] + " radio: " + circle.getRadius(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (distance[0] < circle.getRadius()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "dentro del rango: "
                            + distance[0] + " radio: " + circle.getRadius() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,8.0f));
                locationText.setText("estas en [" + longitudeF + " ; " + latitudeF
                        + "] ");
                Log.d(TAG, "onMyLocationChange: 1" + distance);
            }
        };
    }

    private void drawMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position) {
        double radiusInMeters = 300;
        int strokeColor = 0xffff0000; //red outline
        int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000; //opaque red fill

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position).radius
                (radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
        circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position);
        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat it only shows an array but it looks always changing when if moves the marker

> 01-04 04:03:31.766 5838-5864/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.location.Location.isFromMockProvider, referenced from method com.google.android.location.util.am.e
>   01-04 04:03:31.766 5838-5864/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 995: Landroid/location/Location;.isFromMockProvider ()Z
>   01-04 04:03:31.766 5838-5864/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0019
>   01-04 04:03:31.822 9501-9501/com.jhon.co.divi D/MyApp: onMyLocationChange: 1[F@53a75360
>   01-04 04:03:31.834 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.Looper.quitSafely, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.b.c.onDestroy
>   01-04 04:03:31.842 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1351: Landroid/os/Looper;.quitSafely ()V
>   01-04 04:03:31.842 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
>   01-04 04:03:31.854 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent V/GeofencerHelper: Initializing geofence's system cache.
>   01-04 04:03:31.862 5838-5858/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/GeofenceStateCache: Recovered 0 geofences.
>   01-04 04:03:31.886 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.Process.myUserHandle, referenced from method com.google.android.location.internal.server.o.f
>   01-04 04:03:31.886 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1464: Landroid/os/Process;.myUserHandle ()Landroid/os/UserHandle;
>   01-04 04:03:31.886 5838-5838/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00a7

This is how it looks:

[image]

I can't figure out why it always return 0.0 and doesn't make the validation in `Location.distanceBetween`.

Comment: Have you tried logging the latitude and longitude values returned by both marker and circle?, I feel like they are having the same values

Comment: You are right the are having same values, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to compare a circle and marker which is created with the same position (see drawMarkerWithCircle) and compare them. If you want to track the distance  between those two marker or circle, you must create a mechanism (maybe a temporary variable) that will hold the original location and compare it to the new location.

Comment: Hi gRenzFries, i solve my problem with your advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
            postRef.addChildEventListener( new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               // Toast.makeText(this, "if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            } else {

                String latitude_Display = dataSnapshot
                        .child( "Pro_file" )
                        .child( "bpro_latitude" )
                        .getValue().toString();

                String longitude_Display = dataSnapshot
                        .child( "Pro_file" )
                        .child( "bpro_longitude" )
                        .getValue().toString();

                //Toast.makeText(this, "else " + latitude_Display + "\n" + longitude_Display, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                String latLng = latitude_Display;
                String latLng1 = longitude_Display;

                double latitude_C = Double.parseDouble(latLng);
                double longitude_C = Double.parseDouble(latLng1);

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
                Criteria crit = new Criteria();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( locationManager.getBestProvider( crit, false ) );
                float[] distance = new float[2];
                CircleOptions circleOptions_b = new CircleOptions();
                circleOptions_b.center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                circleOptions_b.radius(100000);
                Location.distanceBetween( latitude_C, longitude_C,
                circleOptions_b.getCenter().latitude, circleOptions_b.getCenter().longitude, distance);

                if( distance[0] > circleOptions_b.getRadius()  ){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "the user Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "the user Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //do something
                    listUsers.add( dataSnapshot
                            .child("Pro_file")
                            .getValue(user.class) );

                    displayUsers(listUsers);
                    find_myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            find_myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            find_myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


}
```